# How to make a plugin for this Gradle task?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, plugins, gradle-plugin

I have some Gradle config in my project that creates an additional source set for integration tests, and a task to run them:

```
    sourceSets {
        create("integrationTest") {
            compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().compileClasspath + sourceSets.main.get().output
            runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().runtimeClasspath
        }
    }

    task("integrationTest", type = Test::class) {
        testClassesDirs = sourceSets["integrationTest"].output.classesDirs
        classpath = sourceSets["integrationTest"].runtimeClasspath
        outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    }

    tasks.withType<Test> {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
```

I'm converting this to a plugin, so I can easily reuse it:

```
class IntegrationTestPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.plugins.withType(JavaPlugin::class.java) {
            val sourceSets = project.properties["sourceSets"] as SourceSetContainer
            val sourceSet = sourceSets.create("integrationTest") {
                val main = sourceSets.getByName("main")
                compileClasspath += main.compileClasspath + main.output
                runtimeClasspath += main.runtimeClasspath
            }

            project.tasks.create("integrationTest", Test::class.java) {
                useJUnitPlatform()
                testClassesDirs += sourceSet.output.classesDirs
                classpath = sourceSet.runtimeClasspath
                outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I run the `integrationTest` task from the plugin, it will also try to run tests from the `test` source set, and then fail to do so because they are not on the classpath.

How do I fix the plugin so it doesn't try to do that?

And for bonus points: Why does the plugin behave differently than the original code?

Comment: `testClassesDirs = ` in the first case and `testClassesDirs +=` in the second?

Comment: Could it be that simple? I must have been staring at this too long